# Detect module position that's calling the script

Tags: joomla, module

I've written a module that can be displayed on several places on the same place. Depending on the module position the executed query differs a bit. But how to find out the module position that calls the script?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that part :-)
I tried JModuleHelper, but on both places on the pages the module information of the first call is shown.

Because the module position is different I can't use 
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mainmenu', 'Resources' );

Comment: $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_opstap_slider');
echo $module->position;

This results in two time the same position name. Apparantly when a module is called for a second time, position isn't overwritten